# Xml to Xml - Xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to learn xslt
but have no good tutorials where i can find all info together

please help me here...

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute namespace="{namespace-uri()}" name="{name()}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

this is some code which i found at stackOverFlow
But i dont understand , what "exactly" the expressions
"@*|node()", "@*", "{namespace-uri()}", "name()"

means...help me.....

Comment: check out http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp for a great tutorial on XSLT

Comment: w3schools  is the first place where i go around for any web based techs...but it doesn't say much about Xml to Xml writing using Xslt...especially about the keywords previously mentioned...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd point out that you can find this and more in [the XPath specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath.html).

The short version is that an `@` prefix indicates an attribute node (as opposed to element and text nodes, usually), `*` means "any name" more or less (so `*` matches all elements and `@*` all attributes), `node()` matches any element or text node, `|` is the "join" or "union" operator (so `@*|node()` matches all element, text, and attribute nodes).

Moving on to the less common stuff, `namespace-uri()` returns the full URI for the namespace of the "context node" (think "this" in OO terms) and `name()` returns the name of the current node, with the appropriate namespace prefix (note that the prefix is take from the XSLT file, not the XML file, if they differ).

Finally, `{...}` is a way to include an XPath expression in an attribute value where they aren't normally allowed.  You'll most commonly see them in constructs like `<a href="{link/url}">`.

I realize that's probably a pretty thick read.  Hopefully, it helps, though.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Ben, that really helped...
i wasn't aware that these syntax belongs to XPath.
this one helped.

Comment: That's really common, it seems!  But when I was learning XSLT I actually referred to the XPath specs more often than the XSLT ones.  Good luck with your learning, I had a lot of fun with it.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the Zvon tutorials and references which have very comprehensive examples:

http://www.zvon.org/

and for XSLT:

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/index.html